# Disable negative indexing when checking neighbours in a matrix in Python

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, indexing, numpy-ndarray

So I have the following code with given input:

```
import numpy as np

x = np.matrix([[1,1,1,1,0],
               [1,1,1,0,0],
               [1,1,0,0,0],
               [1,0,0,0,0]])
print(x)

def MIZ(mat,check):
    for j in range(0,mat.shape[0]):
        for i in range(0,mat.shape[1]):
            try:
                if mat[i,j] == 1:
                    if mat[i+check,j] == 0 or \
                       mat[i-check,j] == 0 or \
                       mat[i,j+check] == 0 or \
                       mat[i,j-check] == 0:
                           mat[i,j] = 2
            except:
                pass
    return mat
            
print(MIZ(x,1))
```

The idea is is quite simple; in that all 1s that lie next to 0s are converted to 2s. The "check" parameter here should ideally be adjustable such that if "check=2" 1s that have a 0 a space away are also converted to a 2, and so on. Now the problem arises with the first element in the matrix (index = 0,0), because then i-1 and j-1 are both -1 and for my purposes I want to avoid this and limit it ONLY to surrounding elements.

The current result of the code is:

```
[[2 2 2 2 0]
 [2 1 2 0 0]
 [2 2 0 0 0]
 [1 0 0 0 0]]
```

There's also the issue of the lowermost 1 not being converted to 2 but that's a secondary issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check before indexing that you are in range.
Like that (btw look that i changed `i` and `j` in the loops):

```
def in_range(index, range_length):
    return -range_length <= index <= range_length -1


def MIZ(mat, check):
    for i in range(0, mat.shape[0]):
        for j in range(0, mat.shape[1]):
            if mat[i, j] == 1:
                if (in_range(i+check, mat.shape[0]) and mat[i + check, j] == 0) or \
                   (in_range(i-check, mat.shape[0]) and mat[i - check, j] == 0) or \
                    (in_range(j + check, mat.shape[1]) and mat[i, j + check] == 0) or \
                    (in_range(j - check, mat.shape[1]) and mat[i, j - check] == 0):
                    mat[i, j] = 2
    return mat

print(MIZ(x, 1))
```

Input:

```
x = np.array([[1,1,1,1,0],
               [1,1,1,0,0],
               [1,1,0,0,0],
               [1,0,0,0,0]])
```

Output:

```
[[2 2 2 2 0]
 [2 1 2 0 0]
 [2 2 0 0 0]
 [2 0 0 0 0]]
```

edit, changing the "in_range" function should make it that you only access non-negative indices as you want:

```
def in_range(index, range_length):
    return 0 <= index <= range_length -1
```

Input:

```
x = np.array([[1,1,1,1,0],
               [1,1,1,0,0],
               [1,1,0,0,0],
               [1,0,0,0,0]])
```

Output:

```
[[1 1 1 2 0]
 [1 1 2 0 0]
 [1 2 0 0 0]
 [2 0 0 0 0]]
```

Comment: Hi, so while this for sure looks better and solves the lowermost 1 error and at the same time removes the need to use the `try:` statement - which is all great, it still doesn't solve my base problem. In that I would like for the 1s on the top and left edges that are not bordering 0s to remain 1s e.g. the first element of the first row is only surrounded by 1s so it shouldn't become 2 (it does so since `x[-1,0]` and `x[0,-1]` are zero, but I do not want that to trigger and rather focus only on direct neighbors)

Comment: Just to make sure, the expected output should be: `[[1 1 1 2 0]

 [1 1 2 0 0]
 [1 2 0 0 0]
 [2 0 0 0 0]]`
?

Comment: Correct! Yes that would be the output I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

I have not been able to find any clean solution but this does the job. Max(0, value) is also possible but then if you have a negative value it picks 0, which is an index itself.

```
# Function
def no_neg(value):
    if value >= 0:
        return value
    else:
        raise IndexError
```

In your code it looks something like this.
import numpy as np

```
x = np.matrix([[1,1,1,1,0],
               [1,1,1,0,0],
               [1,1,0,0,0],
               [1,0,0,0,0]])
print(x)

def MIZ(mat,check):
    for j in range(0,mat.shape[0]):
        for i in range(0,mat.shape[1]):
            try:
                if mat[i,j] == 1:
                    if mat[no_neg(i+check),no_neg(j)] == 0 or \
                       mat[no_neg(i-check),no_neg(j)] == 0 or \
                       mat[no_neg(i),no_neg(j+check)] == 0 or \
                       mat[no_neg(i),no_neg(j-check)] == 0:
                           mat[i,j] = 2
            except:
                pass
    return mat
            
print(MIZ(x,1))
```